# Please explain the phrase "brutal, callous efficiency" in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Across the fire, Riga was
> binding a struggling deer with his usual brutal, callous **efficiency**.

Why does the author use the word **efficiency** here?
I use Cambridge Dictionary and it says "efficiency" means

> the good use of time and energy in a way that does not waste any

Does it literally mean that Riga was binding the deer without wasting energy and time? What is "brutal, callous efficiency"? I feel that I missed something. Please analyse that context for me.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase could have be written as *"with his usual efficiency."* which just says Riga has some skills and does not waste effort - just as your dictionary said. However, the author wants to emphasise Riga's lack of feeling. He is binding the animal without concern for any pain or distress he causes.

Comment: Contrast the scene with a hospital's emergency department, where the staff would handle an accident victim efficiently but also with compassion.

Comment: Thank you @KateBunting, that is a great comparison.

Comment: Did you mean 'lack of feeling'?

Comment: Good catch @MichaelHarvey, thank you for pointing that out.